# Youtube Embed Won't Display in IE

Tags: html, object, internet-explorer-8, youtube, embed

It won't show up in IE8. I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width:360px; height:295px;" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/nwzbAnyThGU?rel=0&amp;loop=1&amp;showsearch=0">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/nwzbAnyThGU?rel=0&amp;loop=1&amp;showsearch=0" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
</object>
```

I appreciate any help you guys can give me.

Comment: Have you thought about embedding the YouTube video in an iFrame the way YouTube gives you the code when you 'share' it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't going to use the new embed code that uses iframe, then try this one instead:

```
<object width="360" height="295">
   <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/nwzbAnyThGU&rel=0&hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&version=3"></param>
   <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
   <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
   <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/nwzbAnyThGU&rel=0&hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="360" height="295">
   </embed>
</object>
```

The new embed code itself is simply this:

```
<iframe width="360" height="295" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nwzbAnyThGU?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```